# Hide parent css rules on hovering over children in angular js using directives

Tags: angularjs

I m Trying to Applying css rules on Element on mouseover , but when i try to hover a child element , css rules for parent node remain in tact .

When Child Node is selected then Parent Node should be deselected . Please check the JSFiddle

```
<div ng-app="demo_app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">

      <div hover style="padding:20px;">
        Parent
        <div hover style="padding:20px;">
           Children: Sub Parent
           <div hover style="padding:20px;">
              Children: Sub Parent Sub Parent 
              <div hover style="padding:20px;">
                 Content
              </div>

           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>    
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">

</script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('demo_app',[]);

    app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope)
    {

    }]);

    app.directive('hover', function(){

      return {
        restrict: 'AE', 
        link: function($scope, element, iAttrs, controller) 
        {
            var add_button='<div class="hover_plus"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus navplus"></span></a></div>'; 
            element.bind('mouseover',function()
            {

              element.css('outline','');
              console.log(element.parents().css('outline',''));
              element.css('outline','1px solid red');

            });

            element.bind('mouseout',function()
            {
              element.css('outline','1px solid red');
              element.css('outline','');
              element.find('.hover_plus').remove();
            });

        }
      };
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/john_bahar/6yztpn6b/1/

Answer (score 2):

You might want to stop the event to propogate to the parent element, which is also having the same directives and hence same css rules.

Hence all parent and its parent, all of them perform their actions on the **mouseover** event.

So, while binding, you need to stop the event from propogating.

So your mouse over events becomes like:

```
element.bind('mouseover',function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
//other stuff
});
```

and similarly "mouseout" also, but that is not necessary. It is just to remove unnecessary event handlings by parent which are not needed.

Check this way.

PS. your fiddle is empty, when I tried to check that :)